# Can .vtuexe files of vteststudio be executed on something which is not CANOE?

Tags: canoe

I have some .vtuexe files from vteststudio studio and my project doesn't use canoe
Can I execute the test cases with no canoe?
Debugger is Isystem winidea

Answer (score 0):

The .vtuexe file is designed to work only with CANoe. It is not an open source file which you can use in other tools. If your project doesn't use CANoe, then you should not use vTESTstudio.